# Get binded properties in ListViewRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project and added a bool value to enable/disable the extra cells that show by default in ios.

My custom renderer is

```
 public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowExtraCellsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ShowExtraCells", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomListView), true);

    public bool ShowExtraCells
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ShowExtraCellsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ShowExtraCellsProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and my iOS renderer is

```
public class CustomListViewiOS : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {

            var listView = Control as UITableView;
            listView.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            this.Control.TableFooterView = new UIView();
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is I can't find the sender to cast it to the CustomListView to be able to get the value of the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find **Solution** from here.

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {

            var listView = Control as UITableView;
            listView.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            this.Control.TableFooterView = new UIView();
        }
        var element = (your Interface name here / Control which you want to render)this.Element;
        //afterwards you can Access your Properties from **element** Like,
        element.ShowExtraCells = true;
    }
```